# iOS: How do I set the name of an image uploading to server using Restkit

Tags: ios, ios5, restkit

I'm trying to upload an image from the phone to the server.  Everything is working fine, except using the code below it's using "Avatar" as the file name.  So I guess my question is, I'm giving them the choice to choose a picture, or take a picture with the camera.  Do I know which type of file it will be i.e. png, jpg or do I need to figure that out before I upload it?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    //self.avatarImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    self.avatarImage.image = image;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    RKParams* params = [RKParams params];

    NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [params setData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/png" forParam:@"Avatar"];

    NSLog(@"RKParams HTTPHeaderValueForContentType = %@", [params HTTPHeaderValueForContentType]);
    NSLog(@"RKParams HTTPHeaderValueForContentLength = %d", [params HTTPHeaderValueForContentLength]);

    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/user/updateavatar" params:params delegate:self];
}
```

Comment: your code looks fine to me..what error you get?

Comment: The code works fine, my question is since I'm giving them the option to take a picture or one from the gallery do I know what type of file it is?  In order to save it on the server am I saving a png or a jpg or is there a way to tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your answer:

```
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

You are creating a PNG image.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure.